# Receiving Telegram messages on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, api, telegram, message

I'm wondering if its possible to use a Telegram API to connect it to Excel and have it receive messages. Any tips would be helpful!

Comment: Haven't looked to far but looks like HTTP requests to BOT API are a starting point https://core.telegram.org/bots

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create custom software which will login to telegram, use its api and write parsed data to excel. There is no way to connect excel to telegram directly.